# Reading the racial modifier to skills in a monster's stat block

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

Below is a snippet from the stat block of a ghost scorpion:

Skills Perception +4, Stealth +8; Racial Modifiers +4 Perception, +4 Stealth

What is the correct way to interpret the proper bonus to the a stealth roll? Is its Stealth at +12, because the creature has a +4 racial modifier in addition to its standard modifier, or is it +8 because the +4 racial modifier is already included in the +8?

Answer (score 6):

All bonuses, including [racial bonuses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Racial-Bonus), are already figured into the [creature's stat block](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-entry-format). In this case the scorpion has Perception +4 and Stealth +8 total, it's just letting you know where some of the bonus comes from. You can determine this by back-figuring skill points for creature type and INT and seeing that they can't reach those bonuses without the racial bonuses included.